# How to Drag Drop One li to another li with respective images?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I would like to Drag Drop li values to one list to another list.

E.g :
I have to list Items And choosenItems.

Items contains:

```
String
Int
Double
Doller
Rupees
```

ChoosenItems:
If user drog drop Items to Choosen Items that time need to drop that values with related images styles.
E.g: If I am going to drog Doller Means $ sign image, Rupees means Rs image, Int means 123 number image will drop on choosenitems dynamically.

It's possible to do that.  Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#" class="item" id="1">String</a>      
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="2">Int</a>
    </li>
 </ul> 
 <div  class="cart">
 </div>
```

Here is the java script to make elements drag able and drop able and get the dropped elements id's

```
 $(function () {
    $('.item').draggable({
        revert: true,
        proxy: 'clone',
        onStartDrag: function () {
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
            $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index', 10);
        },
        onStopDrag: function () {
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'move';
        }
    });
    $('.cart').droppable({
        onDragEnter: function (e, source) {
            $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'auto';
        },
        onDragLeave: function (e, source) {
            $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
        },
        onDrop: function (e, source) {

            var id=source.id;
// this var id lets you know that which item has been dropped into the cart div .. 
//you can implement the remaining functionality according to your   requirement.
if(id==1)
{
//Load String Image
}
else if(id==2)
{
//Load Int Image
}
        }
    });
   });
```